# ExactTarget for loop with matching on subscriber data

Tags: email, for-loop, exacttarget, ampscript

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue I am having. I am attempting to loop through a data extension, let's call it Inventory, and match back to subscriber data. The Inventory DE has a row called "InventoryId" with numeric fields, as well as a row called "product description" with text. There are subscriber attributes called "purchaesedID1", "purchasedID2", etc and a value of "yes" if they have purchased it, and blank if not. these purchasedID fields correspond with the inventoryID field on the Inventory DE. I'm attempting to loop through the Inventory DE and show a table of all of the inventory ID's they have purchased as well as the description. I'm stuck as to how to do this as I am not sure what the lookup rows would match on.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC question over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it there as well.

Comment: Can you show us your loop?